# Code Access Security is preventing PInvoking Setup API calls

Tags: c#, pinvoke, code-access-security, setupapi

I'm rewording this question since I understand a bit more now.  Originally, what I had was too vague.  I've discovered that I'm being routed by something called "Code Access Security."  This is old-hat to everyone reading this, I'm sure, but not to me.

The application is very large so in a nutshell I have two assemblies.  One is a utilities assembly with various "tools" used throughout the program.  The other is calling upon these tools in order to function.

In the utilities assembly, there are many functions that are PInvoked but the one giving me grief is: SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  My function prototype looks like this:

```
[DllImport("SetupApi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
    SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid deviceInfoSet,
    ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData,
    IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData,
    uint deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize,
    IntPtr requiredSize,
    IntPtr deviceInfoData);
```

In the assembly which uses this function, I'm using the two step process outlined in the remarks in order to gain the understanding of how much space I need to store the DevicePath which is in the SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA structure ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  For example:

```
string GetDevicePath(SafeHandleSeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid hList, SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA infoSet)
{
    IntPtr pReqSize = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
    Marshal.WriteInt32(pReqSize, 0);
    uint reqSize;

    // get the size needed
    PInvoke.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hList,
                                            ref infoSet,
                                            IntPtr.Zero,
                                            0,
                                            pReqSize,
                                            IntPtr.Zero);

    reqSize = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(pReqSize, 0);

    IntPtr pDevInfoDetail = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)reqSize + 4); // +4 for cbSize

    // call again, this time getting the actual data wanted
    PInvoke.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hList,
                                            ref infoSet,
                                            pDevInfoDetail,
                                            reqSize,
                                            IntPtr.Zero,
                                            IntPtr.Zero);

    string path;
    // work .NET magic to read from unmanaged memory the path string and assign it
    // to the above variable.  Deallocate both unmanaged memory blocks.

    return path;
}
```

The most frustrating thing is, these assemblies are used by two different programs.  One is a GUI using the Visual Studio Isolated Shell.  The other is simply a command line program.  When the GUI is running, the above code is called and executes as expected.  In the command line tool however, they fail (as described in the MSDN reference for this Setup API function) with some data about what happened.  At this point, I'm able only to recover a portion of the data that is returned.

This is what comes back from the runtime:

> stem.Security.PartialTrustVisibilityLevel, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

I know this has something to do with Code Access Security but I'm not at all sure how to fix.  Using some suggestions that I've found thus far I've tried this attribute to the assembly (I placed it before the namespace block of code):

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

But this caused other compilation problems.

Please, anything would be most helpful and greatly appreciated.

Andy

Comment: Could you please provide the full exception details, as returned by its ToString() method?

Comment: @Nicole As far as I can tell, no exception is being generated.  Visual Studio isn't breaking on any unhandled exceptions and my code isn't wrapped in try/catch blocks.  My only indication is that the Setup API function returns with error code 1784 (Invalid user buffer) and puts details of the device that exposes the interface into the path member.  Unfortunately, when I increase the size of the buffer to capture it all, nonsensical data is all I get.

Comment: Where are you finding the reference to PartialTrustVisibilityLevel?

Comment: @Nicole I'm not sure I completely understand your question but I'm not directly referencing it at all.  None of my code is.

Comment: I meant the text reference, not a code reference.  In your question, you wrote that "This is what comes back from the runtime: "stem.Security.PartialTrustVisibilityLevel, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"."  Where did you get that string?

Comment: @Nicole et. all, it seems that this appears to be a red herring.  I'm beginning to suspect that the problem has something to do with the bit-width of the compiled assembly (or what JIT makes perhaps).  When I run from the Visual Studio Isolated Shell, the memory window in my debugger shows addresses in 32-bits, but when debugging the command line app, the addresses are 64.  I think this is where the problem is.  Somehow, the region of memory that is being used when using the command line app points to a place that is invalid.  This no longer looks like permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem isn't yet fixed.  However, the problem appears to have nothing to do with Code Access Security as I first thought.  I was being thrown a red herring.  I stepped my way through the code using the memory window in Visual Studio and noticed that these strings were in memory before calling the Setup API function to fill them.  Occasionally, I would get a different block of memory with different contents too, I just usually ended up with the contents I pasted.

The problem actually appears to have something to do with the 64 vs. 32 bit environments (at least, that's my theory at this point).

However, this question isn't the actual problem so I'm "answering" it to close it.

Comment: You have to accept your own answer.  Certainly won't close the question either.